# How to create nested dictionary elements in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want to create a variable which stores this:

```
["messageCode": API_200, "data": {
    activities =     (
                {
            action = 1;
            state = 1;
        }
    );
    messages =     (
                {
            body = hi;
            // ...
        }
    );
}, "message": ]
```

What I have done is this:

```
var fullDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [:]
fullDict["messageCode"] = "API_200" as AnyObject

var data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [:]
fullDict ["data"] = data as AnyObject
```

Is this way is correct and how I can add activities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you explicitly want it as `[String:AnyObject]`:

```
var dict: [String:AnyObject] = ["messageCode":"API_200" as AnyObject,
                                "data": ["activities": [["action":1,
                                                         "state":1]],
                                         "messages": [["body":"hi"]]] as AnyObject,
                                "message": "" as AnyObject]
```

Basically all the root values should be typecasted `as AnyObject`

Or the long way:

```
//Activities is as Array of dictionary with Int values
var activities = [[String:Int]]()
activities.append(["action": 1,
                   "state": 1])

//Messages is an Array of string
var messages = [[String:String]]()
messages.append(["body" : "hi"])

//Data is dictionary containing activities and messages
var data = [String:Any]()
data["activities"] = activities
data["messages"] = messages

//Finally your base dictionary
var dict = [String:AnyObject]()
dict["messageCode"] = "API_200" as AnyObject
dict["data"] = data as AnyObject
dict["message"] = "" as AnyObject
print(dict)
```

**Parsing this to get your data back will be hell; with all the type casts and all.**

**Example** (lets capture `action`):

```
let action = ((dict["data"] as? [String:Any])?["activities"] as? [String:Int])?.first?.value
```

As you can see you need to typecast at every level. This is the problem with using dictionaries in Swift. Too much cruft.

Sure, you could use a third-party library like [`SwiftyJSON`](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to reduce the above to:

```
let action = dict["data"]["activities"][0]["action"]
```

But do you want a dependency just for something as simple as this?

#### Instead...

If your structure is defined then create models instead; as [Ahmad F's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50738557/2857130) suggests. It will be more readable, maintainable and flexible.

**...but since you asked, this is how one would do it with pure `Dictionary` elements.**

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to make dict type of [String: AnyObject]? (Not Any)

Comment: @FattanehTalebi Firstly, why do you want `AnyObject`?

Comment: I want to give this dictionary to an array which accepts dictionary of [String: AnyObject]

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to go with creating a custom Model:

```
struct Model {
    var messageCode: String
    var data: MyData
    var message: String
}

struct MyData {
    let activities: [Activity]
    let messages: [Message]
}

struct Activity {
    var action: Int
    var state: Int
}

struct Message {
    var body: String
    // ...
}
```

Thus you could use it as:

```
let data = MyData(activities: [Activity(action: 1, state: 1)], messages: [Message(body: "hi")])
let myModel = Model(messageCode: "API_200", data: data, message: "")
```

---

However, if you -for some reason- have to declare it as a dictionary, it could be something like this:

```
let myDict: [String: Any] = [
                            "messageCode": "API_200",
                             "data": ["activities": [["action": 1, "state": 1]],
                                      "messages": [["body": "hi"]]
                                     ],
                             "message": ""
                            ]
```

which means that `myDict` is a dictionary contains:

- `messageCode` string.
- `data` as *nested* dictionary, which contains:

  - `activities` array of dictionaries (array of `[String: Int]`).
  - `messages` array of dictionaries (array of `[String: String]`).
- `message` string.

One of the simplest reasons why you should go with the modeling approach is because when it comes to read from `myModel`, all you have to do is to use the dot `.` notation. Unlike working with it as a dictionary, you would have to case its values which could be a headache for some point. For instance, let's say that we want to access the first message body in data messages array:

Model:

```
myModel.data.messages.first?.body
```

Dictionary:

```
if let data = myDict["data"] as? [String: [[String: Any]]],
   let messages = data["messages"] as? [[String: String]],
   let body = messages.first?["body"] {

    print(body)
}
```