# Initialize nested dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want to initialize a nested dictionary in the following way but doesn't work:

`var dict:[Character:Dictionary]`

Here is the dict that I want to create, and the nested level depends on the input

`["a":["b":["c":["d":["e":["f":[:]]]]]]]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create nested dictionary elements in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738324/how-to-create-nested-dictionary-elements-in-swift)

Comment: It's not AnyObject, but a dictionary like `[Character:Dictionary]`

Comment: The purpose of a dictionary is to have values of some sort, So even if you have nested dictionary, the lowest level of nesting should have something other than dictionary for value. From your question it's not clear what it is: `[:]` can mean anything

Comment: Use `var dict:[Character: Any] = ["a":["b":["c":["d":["e":["f":[:]]]]]]]`